# Primefaces Input for Money Input (exactly 2 digits after floating point)

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, masking

I need a PrimeFaces input component, to get/set an amount of cash, that means a Decimal with 2 digits after the floating point.

I tried using inputMask, like

```
<p:inputMask value="#{moneyBean.amount}" mask="999.99"/>
```

But I can't find some way to set a mask that accepts:

1. **1 or more** arithmetic values before floating point
2. Optionally, a floating point "**.**"
3. **0 to 2** arithmetic values after the floating point

For Example, some valid inputs would be:

1. 1234.56
2. 1234.5
3. 2.8
4. 120
5. 120.00

Any ideas to get this input in an efficient way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A regular expression was the best way I've found so far

```
<p:inputText id="numInput" value="#{val.value}" required="true"
    label="#{val.title}" validatorMessage="Not valid Number">
    <p:ajax event="change" process="@form" update=":edit_main" />
    <f:validateRegex pattern="^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]{1,2}+$" />
</p:inputText>
<p:message for="numInput" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Client Side Validation tag visit link

```
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/csvEvent.jsf
```

There are so may example that can help you.
i think your problem will be resolved by these two tag

```
<f:validateDoubleRange minimum="5.5" maximum="8.5" />
```

and

```
<p:clientValidator />
```

tell if not work.

Now i got exactly what you want. you want only two digit after "." 
The `Prime Faces extensions` are provide such type of checks.
Go throw the link

```
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/inputNumber/advanceUsage.jsf
```

it will sure help you.

Comment: Thank you, but validation alone is not enough. I need to restrict the user's input to numericals and '.' In the link you give, the user is allowed to print anything